# Solving for x^2 instead of x

Tags: equation-solving

I would like to test this but is not working for `x^2`??

```
Solve[y == Log[3 - 2 f x^2 + 2 Sqrt[f (3 b - 3 x^2 + f x^4)]], x^2]
```

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps this?:

```
Solve[{y == Log[3 - 2 f x^2 + 2 Sqrt[f (3 b - 3 x^2 + f x^4)]], 
  u == x^2}, {u}, {x}]
(*
  {{u -> -((E^-y (9 - 6 E^y + E^(2 y) - 12 b f))/(4 f))}}
*)
```

Comment: But u should be positive!

Comment: @AliDari What makes you think it's not? Do you mean you want to solve for conditions that ensure `u` is positive?  The question just says to solve for `x^2`.

Answer (score 5):

`Solve` returns a list of rules, which we can apply to any expression we want, for example `x^2`:

```
x^2 /. Solve[y == Log[3 - 2 f x^2 + 2 Sqrt[f (3 b - 3 x^2 + f x^4)]], x] // DeleteDuplicates
(*    {(6 - 9 E^-y - E^y + 12 b E^-y f)/(4 f)}    *)
```

Answer (score 4):

Mathematica gives an error message `Solve::ivar: x^2 is not a valid variable.`

Try instead

```
Solve[y == Log[3 - 2 f x^2 + 2 Sqrt[f (3 b - 3 x^2 + f x^4)]] /.x -> Sqrt[x2], x2]
(*{{x2 -> -((E^-y (9 - 6 E^y + E^(2 y) - 12 b f))/(4 f))}}*)
```